# How to use GNU make's implicit rules to make `foo` from `foo.s`?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Here's my makefile:

```
AS=nasm
ASFLAGS=-f elf64

%: %.o
        ${LD} -o $@ $<
```

Suppose I have a source file `foo.s`, I can run `make foo.o` then `make foo` to make the executable `foo`.

```
$ make foo.o
nasm -f elf64  -o foo.o foo.s
$ make foo
ld -o foo foo.o
```

But if I run `make foo` directly, `cc` is used instead.

```
$ rm foo foo.o
$ make foo
cc -f elf64   foo.s   -o foo
cc: error: elf64: No such file or directory
cc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-f’
make: *** [<builtin>: foo] Error 1
```

This is explained in [the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Catalogue-of-Rules), at the end of the section "Linking a single object file".

How should I write my makefile so that I can run `make foo` to make `foo.o` from `foo.s` and then `foo` from `foo.o` automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clear the default implicit rule with:

```
%: %.s
```

See [Canceling Implicit Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Canceling-Rules) in the make manual.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace:

```
%: %.o
    ${LD} -o $@ $<
```

by:

```
ASEXES  := $(patsubst %.s,%,$(wildcard *.s))

$(ASEXES): %: %.o
    ${LD} -o $@ $<
```

This is a a [Static Pattern Rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern). For each word in `$(ASEXES)`, it instantiates an explicit rule, not a pattern rule. So, it is treated exactly as if you had explicitly written:

```
foo: foo.o
    ${LD} -o $@ $<
```

for each `foo` in `$(ASEXES)`, while pattern rules like:

```
%: %.o
        ${LD} -o $@ $<
```

are treated differently (see the section entitled [Static Pattern Rules versus Implicit Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-versus-Implicit) of the GNU make manual).